# JavaScript Convert Array Of Objects to Arrays For only Specific Key

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects

```
{
    "tags": [{
            "id": "1",
            "data": [{
                    "bs": 1617779042313,
                    "bstp": 1617779099999,
                    "maxA": 1617779050311,
                    "maxV": 10,
                    "minA": 1617779050310,
                    "minV": 10,
                    "q": 3
                },
                {
                    "bs": 1617779100000,
                    "bstp": 1617779519999,
                    "maxA": 1617779100236,
                    "maxV": 10,
                    "minA": 1617779100231,
                    "minV": 10,
                    "q": 2
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "data": [{
                    "bs": 1617779042313,
                    "bstp": 1617779099999,
                    "maxA": 1617779050311,
                    "maxV": 10,
                    "minA": 1617779050310,
                    "minV": 10,
                    "q": 3
                },
                {
                    "bs": 1617779100000,
                    "bstp": 1617779519999,
                    "maxA": 1617779100236,
                    "maxV": 10,
                    "minA": 1617779100231,
                    "minV": 10,
                    "q": 2
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

Output

```
{
    "tags": [{
            "id": "1",
            "data": [
                [1617779050311, 10, 3],
                [1617779100236, 10, 2]
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "data": [
                [1617779050311, 10, 3],
                [1617779100236, 10, 2]
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

I want to format this array of objects into array of arrays

for the "data" key i need to get the value of specific keys and insert in array

specific keys - [MaxA, maxV, q]

How can I do it? Any small help appreciated..:)

efewfewfewfewfewfwefwefewfewfwefewfkfopkr3po2i50493543iropjgoprevm

Comment: What was the problem with your attempt? Are the specific keys dynamically determined, or are they fixed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: You need Array#map and Object.keys. Google their docs, attempt to solve this yourself and put it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map`. See the code snippet below:

```js
const data = [
  {
    bs: 1617779042313,
    bstp: 1617779099999,
    maxA: 1617779050311,
    maxV: 10,
    minA: 1617779050310,
    minV: 10,
    q: 3,
  },
  {
    bs: 1617779100000,
    bstp: 1617779519999,
    maxA: 1617779100236,
    maxV: 10,
    minA: 1617779100231,
    minV: 10,
    q: 2,
  },
];

const keys = ["maxA", "maxV", "q"];

console.log(data.map((d) => keys.map((k) => d[k])));
```

Comment: Hi Som, I want to edit output from input provided in question, any small help appreciated.. :)

Comment: @MitulPanchal It would better if you ask a separate question as you've completed changed the input and output, you can share a link to that question I would be happy to help!